# Leveling carpeted floor without replacing carpet

Tags: repair, flooring, carpet

I have an older house that's previously had some structural work done. The work was done a few years ago, however, I think there was some minor re-settlement in the subsequent months, causing the carpeted upstairs floor to become slightly uneven in one spot. I think the padding is also wearing down, which isn't helping the issue. Oddly, it's limited to the upstairs floor and there's no similar issue in the same spot downstairs.

I'm planning to do a cash out refinance on my house soon and presumably I'll need to do get an appraisal. The issue definitely isn't a show stopper, just something I'd prefer to get fixed before having it appraised.

Here's what the carpeted area looks like more or less (not to scale but gets the idea across). The uneven portion is mainly against the wall that backs up to the stairs, however, it's a 1.5 story (i.e., second story is built into the slant of the roof and when you walk along that area, the slant of the roof/ceiling sort of forces you towards the wall, which makes it more noticeable to walk on.

[image]

I was going to reach out to carpeting companies but thought I'd give a shot to see if there's a quick fix, maybe a material I can put down to do the trick.

The problem area is about 5' x 15' tops. No joke, if I had enough newspaper, I could probably slide it under the padding just enough to lift it up in that spot. That's mostly not serious, but I was just trying to brainstorm materials that would be thin enough to layer so that the area would be slightly less noticeable, even if it's a completely temporary "fix."  I would think that the correct way to do this, whatever that is, would involve sanding something down to make it more even, but that's more that I'm hoping to have to do.

I'm going to eventually get all of the carpet replaced, but just don't want to do it now. Worst case, I'll get a contractor and hopefully it would be a half day fix, but any quicker solutions/advice are appreciated.

Comment: Would you say it is a slant(one end drops down) or a sag(centre  is lower than edges)?  What is the difference from level?  Most levelling problems usually need to check floor joists and maybe raise/fix/slim them up for proper long lasting fix.  Some the sub floor is too thin and it sags a bit.  If just a padding problem, most carpets can be pulled up and then put down again by carpet installers.

Comment: It's probably a very slight slant but more of a sag than a slant.  I did see that I could get some thin padding from Home Depot that might be worth giving a shot.  It's just a little annoying because it wraps around to the stairs, which makes it a little harder to access that area.